# Precedence of Function Calls/Priority of Function Calls

Tags: c++, function, operator-precedence, function-call, order-of-execution

```
int p(int *ptrP){
    *ptrP=20;
    return *ptrP;
}

int q(int *ptrQ){
    *ptrQ=30;
    return *ptrQ;
}

int main(){
    int answer=0,a=10;
    answer=p(&a)+q(&a);      // line Alpha,for discussions sake 
    printf(" answer=%d a=%d ",answer,a ); 
}
```

Output:`answer=50 a=30;`
Swaping the Function calls in *line Alpha* `answer=q(&a)+p(&a)` result in `answer=50 a=20`, this can be justified by saying that fucntion call precedence is left to right, but when we change line alpha to `answer=p(&a)+a+q(&a);` the output is `answer=70 a=30`. 
Where does function calling fit-in the precedence table? Are `foo()+10` and `10+foo` equivalent statements?

Comment: In your revised line with 3 operands, the answer is consistent with being evaluated from left to right.

Comment: Also, which _version_ of C++.  C++20 changed the rules in this area

Comment: Counterintuitively, this has _nothing_ to do with operator precedence.  If we look at `(3+5) * (6+7)`, there's no mathematical rule about if `(3+5)` or `(6+7)` is calculated first. This is a question about "execution ordering".

Comment: I was just reading C++ The complete Reference by Herbert Schildt,(Fourth Ed.) And it says Ref(pg 52) ```Order of Evaluation ::
Neither C nor C++ specifies the order in which the subexpressions of an expression are
evaluated. This leaves the compiler free to rearrange an expression to produce more
optimal code. However, it also means that your code should never rely upon the order
in which subexpressions are evaluated. For example, the expression
x = f1() + f2();
does not ensure that f1( ) will be called before f2( ).``` Does this rule holds in the current version of  C and C++

Answer (score 2):

> Order of evaluation of any part of any expression, including order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified (with some exceptions listed below). The compiler can evaluate operands and other subexpressions in any order, and may choose another order when the same expression is evaluated again.

> There is no concept of left-to-right or right-to-left evaluation in C++. This is not to be confused with left-to-right and right-to-left associativity of operators: the expression a() + b() + c() is parsed as (a() + b()) + c() due to left-to-right associativity of operator+, but the function call to c may be evaluated first, last, or between a() or b() at run time

For a more detailed explanation see the source of the quotation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

So, in your case

```
answer=p(&a)+q(&a);
```

the first function to execute may be `p` or `q`.

Here this rule also applies:

> 11. A function call that is not sequenced before or sequenced after another function call is indeterminately sequenced (the program must behave as if the CPU instructions that constitute different function calls were not interleaved, even if the functions were inlined).

which means that the calls to `p` and `q`, even when inlined,  cannot be optimized in a way that permits their interleaving.

Comment: This is not UB. Your last quote is for C++98, here's [the one](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Undefined_behavior) for C++11 and newer.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes. I overlooked the section title "Sequence point rules (until C++11)". I'll edit he answer.